# GitHub desktop does not allow me to login using 2FA, has any had this issue before?

Tags: macos, github, github-for-mac, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to sign into a GitHub account on the desktop application. I know my username and password are correct because it passes me through and asks for my 2FA code. After I type in the code it says "Unable to authenticate. Try again later". It has been saying this for about a week now. I can sign into my GitHub account on GitHubs web application and the 2FA works fine. Has anyone had this issue with 2FA on GitHub desktop before?

System details: MacOS Sierra 10.12.2

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution anywhere?

Comment: I found that my account was suspended. That might have caused the issue.

Comment: Probably! :-) I finally found that if I cancelled the dialog that came up when I first installed it, and then went into the settings and set up the account there, it worked. Very odd.